# Is there a way to list all current Kestrel server configuration on a running server?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, kestrel-http-server

There are several different ways to **configure a Kestrel server** (**JSON** **file**, **IWebHostBuilder**, **environment variables**) but is there any way to view the entire applied configuration together? It would be nice to read the final outcome after using more than one of these configuration options.

I'm running **.NET 5.0 ASP.NET Core** apps in **Linux Docker containers** and was really hoping for something I could look at via the command line in the running container. Is it all just in memory and this is an impossible ask? I'd even take a **local-only landing page** or something.

I've read all documentation I can find and haven't seen this addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't possible today. File a feature request on ASP.NET Core describing what you would like to see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues

Answer (score 0):

While not quite what I was looking for, I found [IConfigurationRoot.GetDebugView()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationrootextensions.getdebugview) which gives me the information I need. It "generates a human-readable view of the configuration showing where each value came from."

I can't use it in a shell on the web server like I initially asked, but it could be output to a page or API for debugging.